# Getting all possible routes in network analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, routing

The network analyst (ArcGIS 10.3) gives you the best route regarding some impedance.

I want to know if there is the possibility that he gave us ALL the possible routes and not only the best one.

That would be important in order to do a better analysis.

Comment: There would be an infinite number of possible routes between one location and another

Comment: Not in my case because i have a lot of restrictions that simulates a real network. From my point A to point B there are like 3 or 4 options like in "real life"

Comment: @Maksim there's only an infinite number of routes if you allow loops on the network, and allow the algorithm to loop round any number of times.

Comment: See the last comment in this thread...known as the "scaled line barrier concept": [GeoNet Link](https://community.esri.com/thread/63897)

Comment: thank you, that's actually a very clever way to work around the problem